# Repl In Rust as GHCI in Haskell?

Tags: rust

in Haskell as a newbie is very easy to understand how things work, if you are looking for a function that does something, you can just look up for the signature/type on Hoogle.

At the same time if you have a function you don't quite understand how it works, you can look up the signature type in the ghci repl, and play around with it.

I am struggling with Rust to have the same type of experience, every time I end up googling.. isn't there a repl for Rust? can I get an experience similar to that of Haskell?

for instance the best shot in understanding how to manipulate `&str` is to check the docs online? and go through methods? doc.rust-lang.org? or is there a different way to do it more similar to Haskell?

Comment: Why are people voting to close this as opinion-based? It's a perfectly objective topic.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, it's partly objective but not entirely. And the objective part isn't necessarily on-topic as defined in the [help/on-topic]. For example: the last paragraph asks for "the best shot in understanding", which is opinion-based. Asking how to activate Rust's native or official REPL (assuming it has one) it is on-topic, but if there are several third-party ones asking for a REPL is _off-topic_ as it now becomes a resource recommendation request. Personally, I voted to close it on that last reason.

Comment: Rust doesn't have an official REPL. The only ones I know of are [IRust](https://github.com/sigmasd/irust) and [evcxr](https://github.com/evcxr/evcxr), but I haven't used either nor have I used GHCI in Haskell so I have no idea the experience you are looking for or if these are in any way comparable.

Comment: I would recommend for this reading documentation.  You can often infer much of what function does by looking at its signature (although probably not to the extend you can in Haskell). You can also look at the source code itself, you will find a link to the _source_ to the right of every documented item. Rust's standard library is written in very approachable way, and understanding what it does is not that hard.

Comment: You don't have to have internet connection to see documentation of the standard library. If you have installed rust with rustup, you can view a local copy of documentation by running `rustup doc --std`.

Comment: thanks was making sure I wasn't missing out on some way to have the same Haskell experience. I guess is not too bad lookign at the well written doc, just have to get used to it, and is a bit less direct than wiht Haskell. Sorry for the offtopic, but was useful for me. cheers

Comment: You can also get context-sensitive help by using a good IDE that knows about Rust. See https://www.rust-lang.org/tools